# Reading/receiving data from WooCommerce WebHook with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, woocommerce, webhooks

First of all, before asking my question, I would like to state that I have done a lot of research. But unfortunately I couldn't find a solution.

I use WooCommerce with WordPress,
I want to see the order tracking instantly with WebHook, My question may be simple, but I'm stuck.

How can I get an MVC page (c#) and its information with WooCommerce WebHook.

I made the WooCommerce WebHook settings,

[WooCommerce WebHook settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRU3p.png)

Delivery URL https://antiochiadoner.com/test

Sometimes even easy solutions can be heavy :)

Thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: So are you asking how you process the data received from WooCommerce in your MVC controller?

Comment: Hello @Gary , what I actually want to do is to monitor the incoming orders instantly with mvc or web api.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you just need to setup an Action on a Controller that you point WooCommerce to under the webhook setting. When a new order is created in WooCommerce it will post the details of the order through to your defined controller action. So something along the following:

```
[HttpPost, AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
{
     string data = Request.Params["data"];

     return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

You can either define a model with all the properties of the data being sent by WooCommerce, or just access the required parts via the Request.Params collection.